# How to search innerHTML in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, innerhtml

I have a list of users on the page.

Each student has an input filed where user can add tags to their profile. There's a search bar on top of the all the students, ***searchStudentByTags***. I am trying to implement this function, but have not been able to solve it yet. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the StudentContainer component where has the searchStudnetByTags function I write so far but not working

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import Student from "./Student";
import Input from "./Input";

import "../stylesheets/StudentsContainer.scss";

const StudentsContainer = ({ students }) => {
  const [searchByName, setSearchByName] = useState("");
  const [searchByTags, setSearchByTags] = useState("");

  const filteredStudents = useMemo(
    () =>
      students.filter(
        ({ firstName, lastName }) =>
          searchByName.length < 2 ||
          (firstName + " " + lastName)
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchByName.toLowerCase())
      ),
    [students, searchByName]
  );

  const renderStudentsByTagSearch = ({ target }) => {
    setSearchByTags(target.value);
    const studentsContainer = document.querySelector(".students-container");
    const allStudents = studentsContainer.getElementsByClassName("student");
    const nameTags = document.querySelectorAll(".tag");

    for (let i = 0; i < allStudents.length; i++) {
      const student = allStudents[i];
      const tag = nameTags[i];

      if (
        searchByTags.length > 1 &&
        student.contains(tag) &&
        tag.innerHTML.includes(searchByTags)
      ) {
        student.style.display = "";
      } else if (
        searchByTags.length > 1 &&
        student.contains(tag) &&
        !tag.innerHTML.includes(searchByTags)
      ) {
        student.style.display = "none";
      } else if (searchByTags.length > 1 && !student.contains(tag)) {
        student.style.display = "none";
      } else if (searchByTags.length === 0 || !student.contains(tag)) {
        student.style.display = "";
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="students-container">
      <Input
        value={searchByName}
        placeholder="Search by name"
        onChange={({ target }) => setSearchByName(target.value)}
      />
      <Input
        className="tag-input"
        value={searchByTags}
        placeholder="Search by tag"
        onChange={renderStudentsByTagSearch}
      />
      {filteredStudents.map((student) => (
        <Student
          key={student.id}
          student={student}
        />
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};

export default StudentsContainer;
```

This is the Student component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "../stylesheets/Student.scss";
import AddTag from "./AddTag";

const Student = ({ student, addTagClick }) => {
    
  const averageGrade =
    student.grades.reduce((acc, grade) => {
      return parseInt(acc) + parseInt(grade);
    }) / student.grades.length;
  const [isViewScores, setIsViewScores] = useState(false);

  const viewScoreClick = () => {
    setIsViewScores((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <article className="student">
      <figure>
        <img src={student.pic} alt="student" />
      </figure>
      <aside>
        <h2>
          {student.firstName} {student.lastName}
        </h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Email: {student.email}</li>
          <li>Company: {student.company}</li>
          <li>Skill: {student.skill}</li>
          <li>
            Average: {averageGrade}%
            {isViewScores && (
              <ul className="scores">
                {student.grades.map((grade, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={index}>
                      Test {index + 1}: {grade}%
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            )}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <AddTag studentId={student.id} addTagClick={addTagClick}/>
      </aside>
      <button onClick={viewScoreClick} className="view-scores-btn">
        {isViewScores ? "-" : "+"}
      </button>
    </article>
  );
};

export default Student;
```

This is the AddTag component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { generateId } from "../helper";
import Input from "./Input";

const AddTag = ({ studentId }) => {
  const [tag, setTag] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    setTag(target.value);
  };

  const onSubmitClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newTag = {
      tag: tag,
      id: generateId(),
      studentId: studentId,
    };

    setTags((prev) => {
      if (tag) {
        return [newTag, ...prev];
      } else {
        return [...prev];
      }
    });

    setTag("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="tags-container">
        {tags.map((tag) => (
          <button className="tag" key={tag.id}>
            {tag.tag}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmitClick}>
        <Input
          className="add-tag-input"
          placeholder="Add a tag"
          type="text"
          value={tag}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddTag;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to approach this differently.. where the array of tags are available at the top level component - rather than doing DOM manipulation. Move

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
```

Into the StudentsContainer, and pass it down through Students and Add Tag as props, then refactor your search to use tags.

I've added a code sandbox here, with a basic gist of how I'd approach it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-ishizaka-hui8j

Comment: Hi @Squiggs! Thanks for the response! But I still don't get it how to use the tags array to do the search?

Comment: I wrote this as you suggested, but unsure how to combine it with the search by name!
const renderStudentsByTagSearch = () => {
    const allStudents = students.filter((student) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        const tag = tags[i];
        if (tag.studentId === student.id && tag.tag.includes(searchByTags)) {
          return student;
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(allStudents);
    return allStudents;
  };

Answer (score 0):

Theres quite a bit going in this question so we should focus on simplifying the problem by removing everything that is of no concern.

So how do we only render those students who have the tag that we currently are searching for? By using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before we map over `students` and return a `<Student />` for each array item.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const data = [
  {id:1,firstName:"Mickey",lastName:"Mouse",tags:[{id:1,label:"mouse"}]},
  {id:2,firstName:"Donald",lastName:"Duck",tags:[{id:1,label:"duck"}]},
  {id:3,firstName:"Minnie",lastName:"Mouse",tags:[{id:1,label:"mouse"},{id:2,label:"cool"}]}
];

const StudentsContainer = ({ students = data }) => {
  const [searchByTagsValue, setSearchByTagsValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={searchByTagsValue}
        placeholder="Search by tag"
        onChange={(e) => setSearchByTagsValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      {students.length &&
        students
          .filter((student) => shouldStudentDisplay(student.tags, searchByTagsValue))
          .map((student) => <Student key={student.id} student={student} />)}
    </>
  );
};

const Student = ({ student, style }) => (
  <div style={style}>
    <h5>
      {student.firstName} {student.lastName}
    </h5>
    <Tags tags={student.tags} />
    <hr />
  </div>
);

const Tags = ({ tags }) => (
  <ul>
    {tags.map((tag) => (
      <li key={tag.id}>{tag.label}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const shouldStudentDisplay = (tags, searchByTagsValue) => {
  if (!searchByTagsValue) {
    return true;
  }
  return tags.findIndex(({ label }) => label === searchByTagsValue) !== -1;
};

export default StudentsContainer;
```

[image: Edit trusting-voice-os88k]

---

Once you can filter your data in place like above, you need an updater function in `StudentsContainer` that will take a student id, and a new tag name, and update (a localised version of) the students data.

Pass this updater function all the way from `StudentsContainer` down to `Tags` so it can update the data in the ancestor component (commonly referred to as [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling)).

```
const [localStudents, setLocalStudents] = useState(students);
const onSubmitTag = (label, id) => {
  const index = localStudents.findIndex((student) => student.id === id);
  if (index !== -1) {
    const newStudents = [...localStudents];
    newStudents[index] = {
      ...newStudents[index],
      tags: [...newStudents[index].tags, { id: Date.now(), label }]
    };
    setLocalStudents(newStudents);
  }
};
```

[image: Edit immutable-star-0ii2r]

---

As you can see, we aren't really searching through the HTML to hide and show things in an imperative way.

In [react](https://reactjs.org/), we are encouraged to update the source data, and allow the rendered UI to *react* in a declarative way.

> React makes it painless to create interactive UIs. Design simple views for each state in your application, and React will efficiently update and render just the right components when your data changes.
> Declarative views make your code more predictable and easier to debug.